# How to compare 2 columns of a dataframe values with possibilities that are in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to compare 2 columns of a dataframe values with possibilities that are in a list.

I have this list :

```
lst=[[1, 1], [2, 1], [4, 1], [6, 2]] #[Poteau,depart]
```

and this dataframe :

```
data = {'poteau': [2, 6, 3, 4], 'depart': [1, 2, 3, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

I'm expecting this kind of result :

[image]

I tried with df.isin() but it does not work as expected. Does somebody have an idea ?
Thanks !

Comment: Do both items in the list have to be true?  I'm not sure about index 1, where `[6, 2]` is true, but the list item is `[6, 1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `merge` with `indicator` and then filter:

```
merged = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=df.columns),how="left",indicator="Exist")
output = merged["Exist"].eq("both")

>>> output
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
Name: Exist, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the logic, you if you want to use `isin` and check whether either poteau or depart matches:

```
pot, dep = zip(*lst)

df['poteau'].isin(pot) | df['depart'].isin(dep)
```

output:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```